# Eloquent Laravel - Migration e Model

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo de como faço um relacionamento na migration e model, onde esse relacionamento resulta em uma tabela com ids externos.

Exemplo :

Uma revenda por ter nenhum ou n endereços, e um endereço pode ter somente uma revenda.

Esse relacionamento resultaria numa tabela resale_address[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando a versão 5.7 do Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisamos definir a terceira tabela, que é a tabela dinâmica. 
Segue um exemplo

Agora, defina o esquema a seguir no arquivo de migração.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    });
}
```

Defina os relacionamentos :

```
class Category extends Model
{
  public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
  }
}
```

O outro

```
class Product extends Model
{
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
}
```

Para criar um produto faça

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    $product->name = 'God of War';
    $product->price = 40;

    $product->save();

    $category = Category::find([3, 4]);
    $product->categories()->attach($category);

    return 'Success';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! :)